# How to print an argument of a function when it fails?

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to use `possibly()` to print the argument `x` as a message when the function `sum()` fails.

```
library(purrr)
t <- function(x) {
  p <- possibly(sum, otherwise = message(x))
  p(x)
}
```

However, I would not expect the below to retrieve any message, since `sum()` doesn't fail:

```
> t(1)
1
[1] 1
```

Instead, the script below works as expected: sum() fails, thus `t()` prints the message 'a'

```
> t('a')
a
NULL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the other answer, `possibly` simply does something quite different from what you want.

What you want is `tryCatch` (part of base R):

```
t <- function(x) {
  tryCatch(sum(x), error = function (.) message(x))
}
```

```
t(1)
# [1] 1
t('a')
# a
```

Answer (score 3):

The argument `otherwise` of the function `purrr::possibly` is a value but `message(x)` is an R expression. According to the documentation:

> These functions wrap functions so that **instead** of generating side effects through printed output, messages, warnings, and errors, they return enhanced output.